# CSS3 Animation div by div with delay

Tags: jquery, html, css

> I have 3 divs which I'm trying to animate one by one. As a test I
>   want them one by one to move down 50px.

I have the following SCSS

```
    .action {
        margin: 20px 0;
        text-align: center;
        transform: translate(0,0);
        transition: all .5s;
        &.animate {
            transform: translate(0, 50px);
        }
        &.animate-delay-1 {animation-delay: 1s;}
        &.animate-delay-2 {animation-delay: 2s;}
    }
```

And this is my HTML

```
            <div class="actions">
                <div class="action animate animate-delay-0">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                    <span class="person"></span> receives her questions by email
                </div>
                <div class="action animate animate-delay-1">
                    <span class="person"></span> fills in the answers to her questions
                </div>
                <div class="action animate animate-delay-2">
                    <span class="person"></span> receives the results by email
                </div>
           </div>
```

I think i'm doing something wrong? They all animate down at the same time..
It's like the delay is being ignored.. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: where is defined the `animation` property and its keyframes? Could you post the full compiled css code?

Comment: I think that you are confusing transitions and animations. You have a transition set, you don't have any animation, so animation-delay won't work

Answer (score 1):

You want `transition-delay` for transitions. I recently wrote a SASS mixin that might be useful:

```
@mixin increment-transition ($el, $time, $num, $offset: 0) {
    $chain: '';

    @for $i from 1 through $num {
        $chain: $chain + ' + ' + $el;

        & #{$chain} {
            transition-delay: #{$i * $time + $offset}s;
        }
    }
}
```

And you use it like:

```
div.action {
    @include increment-transition(div.action, .05, 40);
}
```

Edit: And it produces something like:

```
div.action {transition-delay: 0}
div.action + div.action {transition-delay: 0.5s}
div.action + div.action + div.action {transition-delay: 1s}
div.action + div.action + div.action + div.action {transition-delay: 1.5s}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use your class `animate-delay-1`

Try this :

```
    <div class="actions">
            <div class="action">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                <span class="person"></span> receives her questions by email
            </div>
            <div class="action animate-delay-1">
                <span class="person"></span> fills in the answers to her questions
            </div>
            <div class="action animate-delay-2">
                <span class="person"></span> receives the results by email
            </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: sorry! forgot to add it, it's added by jQuery. ( added to question )